# Can we create a back button like iOS in Android using the custom shape API

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to know if we can customise a button to show like the Apple iOS button in Android?

The button that I would like to draw is

[image]

If this is possible, can someone give me the pointers to it.

Thanks.

Comment: While this is almost certainly possible, I would discourage you from using a different "go back" paradigm from the standard Android one.

Comment: Definitely at least make sure that the hardware back button still works as expected, if you choose to implement the iOS back.

Comment: Sometimes client are too stupid to think that iOS is the base of all UI design. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.  I'll leave the philosophy to others.  The button background can be replaced with anything you choose.  I saved your back icon above as iphoneback_normal.png.In photoshop I created two more states--focused and pressed

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/buttonNoThx3" 
    android:text="Back" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/iphonebackbutton"
/>
```

Create a state list iphonebackbutton drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/iphoneback_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/iphoneback_focused" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/iphoneback_normal" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [9-patch png](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html).

But using iOS-oriented approach on Android may result in poor User Experience.

Comment: I do know that, and Android devices have the special back button but the client was insisting.

Comment: Here is a good blog, which can be a good argument: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/ And especially this post: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/06/differences-between-android-and-ios-ui.html. This might sometimes help to convince your clients :)